# How to properly restore database from file groups backups?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have very (from my point of view) strange error while trying to restore SQL server DB from a series of filegroup backups.

Here is my corrent config:

I have DB with 2 files 2 filegroups and 1 log file.
1st group (called PRIMARY is not read-only and contains my current data).
2nd is (called HISTORICAL) is read-only.

I also have partitioning.

Because of lack of space I make following:

1. After some  service operations (moving data from PRIMARY to HISTORICAL FG) I make FULL Database backup (each month).
2. After that make FULL backup of both groups and then I make log backup.
3. I make PRIMARY FG full backup each night.
4. I make PRIMARY FG differential backup each hour.
5. I make t-log backup every 15 minutes.

My strategy is to minimize space required for backups.

In case of faliour I wil restore FULL backup from beginning of the month. After that I will restore HISTORICAL backup (which is only one for each month). After that I will restore full PRIMARY FG backup from desired time (I am not sure if I have to restore PRIMARY FG backup after FULL DB backup). As last step I will restore t-log backup and return DB in operational state (if needed).

I do that operations in the past. Right now I receive error that the LSN that I tried to restore is too recent. Why this happends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence may be a bit off for a piecemeal restore you're attempting, in particular when to apply the tlogs. This is what [TechNet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177425.aspx) has documented.

> Piecemeal Restore Under the Full Recovery Model
>
> Under the full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model, piecemeal
>   restore is available for any database that contains multiple
>   filegroups and you can restore a database to any point in time. The
>   restore sequences of a piecemeal restore behave as follows:
>
> •Partial-restore sequence
>
> The partial restore sequence restores the primary filegroup and,
>   optionally, some of the secondary filegroups.
>
> The first RESTORE DATABASE statement must do the following:
>
> ◦Specify the PARTIAL option. This indicates the start of a piecemeal
>   restore.
>
> ◦Use any full database backup that contains the primary filegroup. The
>   common practice is to start a partial restore sequence by restoring a
>   partial backup.
>
> ◦To restore to a specific point in time, you must specify the time in
>   the partial restore sequence. Every successive step of the restore
>   sequence must specify the same point in time.
>
> •Filegroup-restore sequences bring additional filegroups online to a
>   point consistent with the database.